# Как узнать id строки только что выполненного запроса insert?

Tags: insert, sql

Добрый день.

Я вставляю данные (которые, возможно, в таблице уже повторяются), и им присваивается ключ id. Как мне в следующем запросе получить id строки, чтоб в дальнейшем работать с id?
Спасибо!

Comment: Через что вы делаете sql запросы? Возможно новый id уже имеется и его можно получить без дополнительных запросов. Например я знаю в php в mysqli есть mysql_insert_id в котором храниться id сгенерированный при последнем INSERT-запросе

Comment: Может я не понял вопроса, но почему не устраивает

    SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, СУБД-то какая? SQL довольно разный бывает от места к месту.

@dzukp, это не очень надежный способ. В зависимости от уровня изоляции транзакции он может сработать, а может и наврать.

Comment: DESC LIMIT 1 - я тоже подумал. Но если предположить, что в друг в эти доли секунд отправляет ещё один человек - тогда это собъётся

Comment: @TwoRS именно поэтому так делать нельзя, правильный ответ уже дали ниже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

PostgreSQL К запросу добавьте [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-insert.html) "ИМЯ_ПОЛЯ" и вам вернётся значение поля "ИМЯ_ПОЛЯ" новой записи.

Answer (score 4):

В MS SQL, например:

- `select scope_identity()`, чтобы получить последний созданный id в текущем соединении и только текущей области видимости (триггеры и функции игнорируются).
- `select @@identity`, чтобы получить последний созданный id на текущем соединении независимо от области видимости (триггеры и функции учитываются).
- `select ident_curent(‘tablename’)`, чтобы получить последний id на конкретной таблице, созданные на любом соединении.