# Замена Union

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет, знатоки MySQL! Чем можно заменить оператор UNION?

Comment: А какова цель запроса?  Можно заменить Join если нужно сцепить две таблицы по какомуто значению и если ты знаешь, что делаешь. А Union просто сбивает две таблицы в кучу как мусор. У тебя какая цель ?

Comment: Ничем. Это не заменимый оператор. Только на нём всё и держится!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще - никак. Вы бы привели пример, там видно было бы что сделать можно. Там может изначально запрос корявый был, например, такой:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 2
```

Тогда можно заменить так:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 1 OR field = 2
```

Есть еще некоторые примеры, когда можно избавиться от UNION`a, но без примера ответ только **НЕТ**

Comment: Чем не подошёл более простой вариант SELECT * FROM table WHERE field in( 1,2)  ?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, я в комментарии к вашему ответу писал пример, когда это не работает.

Пример из моего ответа - это именно пример одной из ситуаций, когда это сделать можно. Ваш пример - одна из возможных реализаций для конкретной ситуации, но не для всего в целом.

Вообще же, мой ответ был изначально комментарием, цель которого - получить более детальную информацию по вопросу. Просто кто-то из доброжелателей посчитал его ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Традиционно заменяется внешним соединением, но, насколько мне известно, MySQL не поддерживает FULL JOIN.

Comment: да, union нужнен как раз для этого. [link text][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4796911/2604639

Comment: Я че-то не соображу, а как через внешнее соединение можно сделать это:

    SELECT id, name FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT id, name FROM table2

Вроде как внешнее соединение помогает только для примера из комментария, или не?

А в mysql его и правда нет, т.к. соединение таблиц выполняется в цикле. Поэтому строки, отсутствующие в главной таблице, не могут быть включены в результат.

Comment: select coalesce(t1.id,t2.id),coalesce(t1.name,t2.name)
from
table1 t1
FULL JOIN
table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id and t1.name=t2.name

Comment: @BOPOH, надо было сразу спрашивать про union all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE field in( 1,2,3,4,5,6.............)
Либо
```

вообще 1 таблицу  id/name/description и тогда вообще всё просто.Делаете просто эту выборку
    либо
    ----------
    Посмотрите, действительно ли необходимо создавать 2 таблицы? может это однородная информация?
    Как вариант можно создать по другому: 1-я таблица (id/name) tovar ,2-я (id/description) description
    В итоге, когда добавляете описание, просто заносите его в таблицу-2.
    Выборка будет выглядеть select t.id,t.name,d.description from tovar as t inner join description as d on d.id=t.id where t.id in (11,22,33,44,55)  //тоесть выберем 5 этих значений.
    может быть небольшая заморочка при вставке, например, вы вносите данные в 1 таблицу, потом тут же получаете id товара, затем берёте его и вставляете в таблицу описания, если есть описание. Я делал  [так][1] , хотя, может есть и другой вариант
    Опять же, если данные однородные(т.е и в одной и в др таблице, скажем товары) то лучше делать именно так, а не создавать 1 таблицу с описанием, а другую впринципе того же самого по типу, но без описания - потом начнётся головняк по сбору этого всего в кучу.

```
  [1]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/390882/sql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-insert
```

Comment: У меня две таблицы: table1 (id, name) и table2 (id, name, description). У меня есть запрос:

    SELECT id, name FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT id, name FROM table2

И как теперь должен будет выглядеть ваш пример?

Comment: Либо как в ответе, либо может и не имеет смысла создавать 2 разных таблицы, а создать одну просто с 3-мя полями